# Best way to get shape of terrain at 1x1 size for road system?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, terrain

I'm about to create a road system according to shape of terrain at certain position and transfer that mesh data to new mesh renderer.

How can I do that? Is there any good way to do that?
Later that I will use 1x1 road parts in A* pathfinding.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand your question you want to convert the heights of a terrain into a mesh for a certain part of the terrain.

You can use [`Terrain.SampleHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain.SampleHeight.html) to get the height of the terrain an a given point (x,y)

I guess you would need to decide how detailed / grained your result mesh should be for more or less details of the terrain.

Then generate a vertex grid raster and retrieve the heights of the terrain. Something like this

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Takes a section of a terrain between the diagonal startPoint and endPoint
/// and returns a mesh with given vertexCount and shape of terrain heights
/// <summary>
/// <param name="terrain">the given terrain to sample from</param>
/// <param name="startPoint">Start world position of the wanted section</param>
/// <param name="endPoint">End world position of the given section</param>
/// <param name="vertexCount">How many vertices shall be used for the mesh (=granularity)</param>
public static Mesh TerrainSectionToMesh(Terrain terrain, Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 endPoint, Vector2 vertexCount)
{
    // First get the step sizes according to vertexCount
    var sectionSize = endPoint - startPoint;
    var stepX = sectionSize / vertexCount.x;
    var stepZ = sectionSize / vertexcount.z;

    // iterate the size in X and Z direction to get the target vertices
    // This crates a vertex grid with given terrain heights on according positions
    var vertices = new Vector3[vertexCount.x * vertexCount.y];
    var uv = new Vector2(vertices.Length);
    var tangents = new Vector4[vertices.Length];
    var tangent = new Vector4(1f, 0f, 0f, -1f);
    for(var i = 0, z = 0; z < vertexCount.y; z++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < vertexCount.x; x++, i++)
        {
            var position = startPoint + Vector3.forward * stepZ * z + Vector3.right * stepX * x;

            position.y  = terrain.SampleHeight(position);
            vertices[i] = position;

            uv[i] = new Vector2((float)x / vertexCount.x, (float)y / vertexCount.y);
            tangents[i] = tangent;
        }
    }

    // Procedural grid generation taken from https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid
    // This generates the triangles for the given vertex grid
    int[] triangles = new int[vertices.Length * 6];
    for (int ti = 0, vi = 0, y = 0; y < vertexCount.y; y++, vi++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < vertexCount.x; x++, ti += 6, vi++) 
        {
            triangles[ti] = vi;
            triangles[ti + 3] = triangles[ti + 2] = vi + 1;
            triangles[ti + 4] = triangles[ti + 1] = vi + vertexCount.x + 1;
            triangles[ti + 5] = vi + vertexCount.x + 2;
        }
    }

    // Finally create the mesh and fill in the data
    var mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.uvs = uvs;
    mesh.tangents = tangents;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    return mesh;
}
```

Procedural grid generation taken from https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid

---

*Note that I am typing this on a smartphone and can not test it right now. But I hope the idea gets clear*